# audio control in layout

Tags: android

i want to add audio control in my layout as available at https://market.android.com/details?id=com.faithcomesbyhearing.android.bibleis&feature=search_result

is he used image or there is some inbuilt audio control which i can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a website that lists all the built in Android Drawables included with the system: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Not all of these are publicly accessible through your code.  I did a quick glance and it does not appear that audio control buttons are included in the system drawables.  You will probably need to create your own.

Good luck!